# HBase : Master Not Running Exception (HDP SandBox)

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to write a Java Client to access HBase from my mac client to HBASE server running in VM. (HDP SandBox 2.2).  This is the code I am using. I saw similar posts but none of those answers solved my problem. I verified that HBASE is running in VM and I can access and create tables using HBASE Shell.

```
 {
    try
    {
        System.out.println( "HBase Client!" );
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.clear();
        conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.240.131:6000");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.240.131");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        System.out.println("HBase running !");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("HBase not running !");
    }

}
```

I verified the IP and ports , everything is correct as per HBASE-site.xml.

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Can you check the log?

Answer (score 0):

The `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` should be a host name and not the IP address. Have that mapping set in the hosts file and use the host name within the Configuration.

Comment: It didn't help ! When I debug, it can talk to zookeeper , but return exception on Master Running. But I can see HMaster running when I do JPS